# Calculating probabilities of simulated random variables in R

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, probability, exponential

I have the following graph:

[image]

I need to travel from A to B. **I also assume that I am taking the fastest route from A to be every day**.

The travel times (in hours) between the nodes are exponentially distributed. I have simulated them, with the relevant lambda values, in R as follows:

```
AtoX <- rexp(1000, 4)
AtoY <- rexp(1000, 2.5)
XtoY <- rexp(1000, 10)
YtoX <- rexp(1000, 10) 
XtoB <- rexp(1000, 3)
YtoB <- rexp(1000, 5)
```

I calculated the average travel time everyday in R as follows:

```
AXB <- AtoX + XtoB
AYB <- AtoY + YtoB
AXYB <- AtoX + XtoY + YtoB
AYXB <- AtoY + YtoX + XtoB 

TravelTimes <- pmin(AXB, AYB, AXYB, AYXB)
averageTravelTime <- mean(TravelTimes)
```

I'm now trying to find the following for every single day:

1. With which probability is each of the four possible routes from A to B taken?
2. What is the probability that I have to travel more than half an hour?

For (1), I understand that I need to take the cumulative distribution function (CDF) P(x <= X) for each route.

For (2), I understand that I need to take the cumulative distribution function (CDF) P(0.5 => X), where 0.5 denotes half an hour.

I have only just started learning R, and I am unsure of how to go about doing this.

Reading the documentation, it seem that I might need to do something like the following to calculate the CDF:

```
pexp()

1 - pexp()
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let R1, R2, R3, R4 be, in some order, random variables corresponding to the total time of the four routes. Then, being sums of independent exponential random variables, each of them follows the Erlang or the Gamma distribution (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Related_distributions)).

To answer 1, you want to find P(min{R1, R2, R3, R4} = R_i) for i=1,2,3,4. While the minimum of independent exponential random variables is tractable (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables)), as far as I know that is not the case with Erlang/Gamma distributions in general. Hence, I believe you need to answer this question numerically, using simulations.

The same applies to the second question requiring to find P(min{R1, R2, R3, R4} >= 1/2).

Hence, we have

```
table(apply(cbind(AXB, AYB, AXYB, AYXB), 1, which.min)) / 1000 
#     1     2     3     4 
# 0.312 0.348 0.264 0.076
```

and

```
mean(TravelTimes >= 0.5)
# [1] 0.145
```

as our estimates. By increasing 1000 to some higher number (e.g., 1e6 works fast) one could make those estimates more precise.

Comment: Hi again Julius! And thank you once again for the assistance! With regards to mean(TravelTimes >= 0.5), isn't this referring to the overall (across all days) mean? Shouldn't we be focusing on the probability that it is >= 0.5 for each day? Or am I misinterpreting it again?

Comment: @ThePointer, `mean(TravelTimes >= 0.5)` is a handy trick. `TravelTimes >= 0.5` is a logical vector with `TRUE` in those days when it takes more than 30 minutes. Hence, we would like `sum(TravelTimes >= 0.5) / 1000`, but `mean(TravelTimes >= 0.5)` is exactly the same. In this case we estimate the parameter `p` of a Bernoulli random variable being 1 when it takes more than 30 minutes and 0 otherwise. (`1 * (TravelTimes >= 0.5)` are realizations of this random variable.)

Comment: Ahh, I see. Wow, thanks so much for the help again! Really enlightening answers!